# How can I test subs in a perl programs with Test::More without losing the programs exit code?

Tags: perl, testing, console-application

When writing small to medium size perl programs I have functions that I would like to test with "Test::More".

The idea is to be able to call my program like "./supertool.pl --test" to do the tests. While beeing able to use "./supertool.pl" for normal program usage.

But when I add "use Test::More qw(no_plan);" in the head section it garbles the program output and its exit code.

Here's an example which can be called in console like: './supertool.pl ; echo $? ; echo "Expected: 0"'.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More qw(no_plan);

if (0)
{
        note("one test");
        test__x();
        done_testing;
}

exit(0);

sub test_x
{
        ok( 1, "1 is ok" );
}
```

The output is:

```
1..0
255
Expected: 0
```

But I whished the output to be

```
0
Expected: 0
```

Is it possible to tweak Test::More into not printing "1..0" and into not garbling the programs exit code when doing no tests?

Comment: I would recommend using [`Test2`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test2). Using [`Test2::Tools::Basic`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test2::Tools::Basic) works fine here.

Comment: Why would you not want the test output? And why would you run the tests from the code you're testing? The tests should live separately and run on their own, they're not part of the application itself.

Comment: I want the test output only when calling the program with parameter "--test".
How would you test the subs defined in the program from a seperate script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to get the behavior you want.

One way is to tell it that you won't run tests, per that command-line option

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Test::More;

my $run_tests = shift;

if ($run_tests) { 
    Test::More->builder->no_plan;
} 
else {
    Test::More->builder->output('/dev/null'); 
    Test::More->builder->skip_all('Not testing');
}
#...

if ($run_tests) {
    note("one test");
    test_x();
}

sub test_x { ok( 1, "1 is ok" ) }
```

The message for skipping won't be seen as the output is redirected to `/dev/null`, as desired, but is provided as an example (and there must be something there).

I use methods from the backend [Test::Builder](https://perldoc.perl.org/Test/Builder.html) module (`Test::More->builder` returns its object) to set a plan/skip, even as there is a `plan` function in `Test::More` itself.

This is for consistency, since for `output` we do need `Test::Builder`, and as further examples of `Test::Builder`, where one can find many more tools in cases where that may be needed. The `Test::More` is built upon this moduel and I suggest a good perusal of it.

An alternative to declaring `no_plan` is to use `done_testing` at the very end of the program, conditioned on `$run_tests` (but not in `END` block, see docs).

Another way is to place all tests in `SKIP` blocks, used for [conditional testing](https://perldoc.perl.org/Test/More.html#Conditional-tests)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Test::More qw(no_plan);

my $run_tests = shift; 
    
SKIP: {
    skip_test() if not $run_test;

    note("one test");
    test_x();
}


sub test_x { ok( 1, "1 is ok" ) }

sub skip_test {
    Test::More->builder->output('/dev/null'); 
    skip "Not testing";
}
```

where output is again sent to `/dev/null`, as desired in the question.

We can also use `Test::Builder` methods directly, either `skip`

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';    
use Test::More qw(no_plan);

my $run_tests = shift;

if ($run_tests) {
    note("one test");
    test_x();
}
else { skip_test() }


sub test_x { ok( 1, "1 is ok" ) } 

sub skip_test {
    Test::More->builder->output('/dev/null');
    Test::More->builder->skip;
}
```

or perhaps `reset`, for different circumstances or context

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Test::More qw(no_plan);

my $run_tests = shift;

if ($run_tests) {
    note("one test");
    test_x();
}
else { Test::More->builder->reset }
    
# At the very end of the program (not in END block though)
done_testing if $run_tests;

sub test_x { ok( 1, "1 is ok" ) }
```

where we're now best off using `done_testing` in the end.

All of these print nothing and have exit code `0` when the program is invoked without any arguments, or run tests and print messages when invoked with a "true"  argument.<sup>†</sup>  All of them were tested with more (than 1) testing blocks, omitted here for brevity.

The need to deal with some details above comes up because the testing framework is intended to be used in dedicated programs, not for testing pieces in a running program.  And while it is possible to use it this way as well some things get more complicated.

See [Test2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test2), or perhaps its suite [Test2::Suite](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test2::Suite), for a newer alternative.

---

<sup>†</sup> That is, "true" for Perl when passed to the program, so not `0` or empty string `"''"`

Comment: I am very happy & thankful for your detailed answer! I've now inserted "done_testing; exit;" at the end of the "if ($run_tests)" block. A line "Test::More->builder->reset;" after that block resets the tester when not testing. Thank you! :-)

Comment: @t3o Great, thanks for saying that -- glad to hear it helps :).  That `done_testing` is a nice way so to not have to worry about number of tests.  Note that  If you have multiple blocks then it has to go in the end (like in my last example) since you can't have it multiple times (it warns)